# Opening an iframe from another iframe using JQuery's Colorbox plug-in

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I need to open an iframe (Frame 1) and from frame1 i need to open frame2 using [jquery colorbox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/).

I have used the following script from a page to open frame1:

```
function ViewUser(Id) {
       $.colorbox({ href: '/user/View/' + Id + '?popup=1', iframe: true, width: "100%", height: "100%", title: 'View User', overlayClose: false, escKey: false, onLoad: function() { $('#cboxClose').hide() }, onComplete: function() { $('#cboxClose').show() } });
}
```

I have added the following script from frame1 to open frame2, but its not opening the page (just opens a blank colorbox).

```
function UpdateUser(Id) {     
  parent.$.colorbox.close();
  parent.$.colorbox({ href: '/User/Update/' + Id + '?popup=1', iframe: true, width: "100%", height: "100%", title: 'Update User', overlayClose: false, escKey: false, onLoad: function() { $('#cboxClose').hide() }, onComplete: function() { $('#cboxClose').show() } });
}
```

Am i missing anything here?

Answer (score 1):

For me, it worked by simply by leaving out the `close()` call:

```
function UpdateUser(Id) {     
  parent.$.colorbox({ href: '/User/Update/' + Id + '?popup=1', iframe: true, width: "100%", height: "100%", title: 'Update User', overlayClose: false, escKey: false, onLoad: function() { $('#cboxClose').hide() }, onComplete: function() { $('#cboxClose').show() } });
}
```

This will load the new content into the old `colorbox`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Modified updateUser as:

```
function UpdateUser(Id) {
  $.fn.colorbox({
    href: '/User/Update/' + Id + '?popup=1', 
    iframe: true, 
    width: "100%", 
    height: "100%", 
    title: 'Update User', overlayClose: false, 
    escKey: false, 
    onLoad: function() { 
      $('#cboxClose').hide() 
    }, 
    onComplete: function() { 
      $('#cboxClose').show() 
    }
  });
}
```

Same way modified **$.colorbox** to **$.fn.colorbox** inside ViewUser().
No need to colobox close and all stuff.